# Can't get webpage to load when on Selenium Chrome Driver and tried years old solutions, need new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I need help building a bot with python selenium chrome driver that bypasses gumtree.com.au login page. When the the chrome driver goes to the specified page

> https://www.gumtree.com.au/t-login-form.html

It loads nothing, just a blank white page. However, when I plug it into any browser manually, it loads perfectly. I can't login get it to load with selenium chrome driver at all and I've tried changing headers, using headless driver, and using vim to change all cdc_ texts globally (yes, its correct, I've triple checked).

Used this useragent class (actually have to import package fake-useragent):

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
```

Snippet of headless driver:

```
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={random_header}')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random_header}")
```

Couple of questions:

1. What should I do? Open to using other automated tool as well.
2. How to build a bot that goes undetected to most sites, if not all?
   Especially the ones that are trying to prevent scraping (I'm not
   scraping, I'm just assuming they get it the worst)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - I have to get driver to visit homepage first, sleep for 5 secs, then jump to login page. If bot goes directly to login page its a no load.